# Least square minimization

Tags: r, least-squares

I hope this is the right place for such a basic question. I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/how-to-minimize-residual-sum-of-squares-of-an-exponential-fit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260017/how-to-set-a-weighted-least-squares-in-r-for-heteroscedastic-data) solutions quite articulated, hence they do not help me to get the fundamentals of the procedure.
Consider a random dataset:

```
x <- c(1.38, -0.24, 1.72, 2.25)
w <- c(3, 2, 4, 2)
```

How can I find the value of μ that minimizes the least squares equation [image] :

The package `manipulate` allows to manually change with  bar the model with different values of μ, but I am looking for a more precise procedure than "try manually until you do not find the best fit".

**Note:** If the question is not correctly posted, I would welcome constructive critics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could proceed as follows:

```
optim(mean(x), function(mu) sum(w * (x - mu)^2), method = "BFGS")$par
# [1] 1.367273
```

Here `mean(x)` is an initial guess for `mu`.

Comment: In this particular case, `coef(lm(x~1,weight=w))[1]` will also produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here's a little algebra:
We want to find mu to minimise

```
S = Sum{ i | w[i]*(x[i] - mu)*(x[i] - mu) }
```

Expand the square, and rearrange into three summations. bringing things that don't depend on i outside the sums:

```
S = Sum{i|w[i]*x[i]*x[i])-2*mu*Sum{i|w[i]*x[i]}+mu*mu*Sum{i|w[i]}
```

Define

```
W = Sum{i|w[i]}
m = Sum{i|w[i]*x[i]} / W
Q = Sum{i|w[i]*x[i]*x[i]}/W
```

Then

```
S = W*(Q -2*mu*m + mu*mu) 
  = W*( (mu-m)*(mu-m) + Q - m*m)
```

(The second step is 'completing the square', a simple but very useful technique).

In the final equation, since a square is always non-negative, the value of mu to minimise S is m.