# R: partial correlation for meta analysis

Tags: r, statistics

First of all, I'm new to R so I'm sorry if whatever I'm going to ask is dumb or redundant. I tried to find an answer to my question on the website but I couldn't find it.

What I'm attempting to do is a meta-analysis. Unfortunately, I have different dependent variables and different independent variables for almost every study of my meta-analysis so I need to compute partial correlation coefficient for my effect size, which are not available in the `metafor` \ `meta` packages. I found the `popcorn` package but I cannot get it to work.

My dataset has been created on excel and then has been imported as csv:

```
Codebook <- read.csv("~/R/Codebook.csv", sep=";", dec=",")
```

My dataset is composed by several columns indicating different dependent variables using a dummy (i.e. 1 if the study uses ROA, 0 otherwise, 1 for ROE 0 otherwise etc.) and columns with the independent variable coefficient, the independent variable SE, its T-stat and finally each study's degrees of freedom. Here's part of the dput() outcome, mostly the dependent variable dummies and the ind variables:

```
structure(list(study = structure(c(39L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 73L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 74L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L), .Label = c("10A", 
"10B", "10C", "11A", "11A-1", "11B", "11B-1", "12A", "12B", "13A", 
"13B", "14A", "14B", "14C", "14D", "15A", "15A-1", "15A-2", "15B", 
"15B-1", "15B-2", "16A", "17A", "17A-1", "17B", "17B-1", "18A", 
"18A-1", "18B", "18B-1", "18C", "18C-1", "18D", "18D-1", "19A", 
"19A-1", "19B", "19B-1", "1A", "20A", "20A-1", "20B", "20B-1", 
"20C", "20C-1", "20D", "20D-1", "21A", "22A", "22A-1", "22B", 
"22B-1", "23A", "23B", "24A", "24A-1", "24A-2", "24B", "24B-1", 
"24B-2", "24C", "24C-1", "24C-2", "25A", "26A", "27A", "2A", 
"2A-1", "2A-2", "3A", "3B", "4A", "4B", "5,00E-01", "5A", "5A-1", 
"5B", "5B-1", "5C", "5C-1", "5D", "5D-1", "5E", "5F", "5F-1", 
"6A", "7A", "7B", "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D", "9A", "9A-1", "9B", 
"9B-1"), class = "factor"), dv_ros = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_roa. = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_roarat = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
dv_droa = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_roe. = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_roerat = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
dv_tq = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_Inv = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), dv_ag. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_nop = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_rota. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), dv_odpa = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dv_grows = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), iv_dummyshare = c(NA, 0.043, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, NA, NA, 0.02, NA, NA, -0.02, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_dummyshare = c(NA, 3.5833333, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.62, NA, NA, 3.44, NA, NA, -2.23, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_dummyshare = c(NA, 0.012, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.019084, NA, NA, 0.005814, NA, NA, 
0.0089686, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_dummyshare = c(NA, 
0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 
NA, 0.95, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), iv_share = c(NA, NA, 0.092, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.041, NA, 0.003, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.15, NA, NA, 0.16, NA, 
NA, -0.23, NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_share = c(NA, NA, 1.3142857, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.7, NA, 2.93, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.09, NA, NA, 2.2, NA, NA, 
-2.76, NA, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_share = c(NA, NA, 0.07, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0087234, NA, 0.0010239, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0717703, NA, NA, 
0.0727273, NA, NA, 0.0833333, NA, NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_share = c(NA, 
NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, 0.95, 
NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA), iv_mainshare = c(-0.003, NA, 
NA, -0.005, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.667, NA, NA, -0.02, -0.007, NA, NA, 1.56, 
NA, -1.28, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.009, -0.132, 
-0.0109, 0.0987, 0.0992, -0.0325, -0.174, 0.00192, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.017, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_mainshare = c(-1.121, NA, NA, -0.1923077, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -1.7015306, NA, NA, -0.5, -0.175, NA, NA, 1.64, NA, -0.58, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.35, -5.51, -0.6855346, 
0.7477273, -0.75, -3.04, -2.19, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.41, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), sd_iv_mainshare = c(0.0026762, NA, NA, 0.026, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.392, 
NA, NA, 0.04, 0.04, NA, NA, 0.9512195, NA, 2.2068966, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0038298, 0.0239564, 0.0159, 
0.132, -0.1322667, 0.0106908, 0.0794521, 0.0096, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0031423, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_mainshare = c(0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.99, 0.99, 0, 0, 0, 0.99, 0.95, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), iv_topshare = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -0.1342, NA, -0.0587, NA, -0.1451, NA, -0.153, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.098, NA, -0.009, NA, -0.023, NA, -0.023, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_topshare = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.24, NA, -2.12, NA, -4.67, 
NA, -5.12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.89, NA, -0.34, NA, -0.54, 
NA, -0.57, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_topshare = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0215064, NA, 0.0276887, 
NA, 0.0310707, NA, 0.0298828, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.03391, 
NA, 0.0264706, NA, 0.0425926, NA, 0.0403509, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), sig_iv_topshare = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.95, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), iv_multirel = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0153975, -0.0099928, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-3.87, -1.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -7e-04, NA, 
NA, -3e-04, NA, NA, 0.0027, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_multirel = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-3.03, -0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.375, -2.7166667, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1.1650469, NA, NA, 4.4171734, NA, NA, 0.0009231, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_multirel = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.0050817, 0.049964, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.72, 0.6, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0006008, NA, NA, -6.79e-05, NA, NA, 
2.925, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), sig_iv_multirel = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, 0.99, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, 
0.95, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), iv_bankloan = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.783, -0.497, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.03, -0.75, NA, -17.09, NA, -25.51, -10.564, -5.698, 
-2.734, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.673, NA, 0.138, NA, -0.0233, 
NA, -0.0216, NA, -0.032, NA, -0.0185, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -17.0327, NA, -1.412762, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.19, NA, NA, -0.19, NA, NA, -0.19, 
NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_bankloan = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-6.12, -3.91, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.75, -1.9230769, NA, -8.33, NA, 
-8.21, -29.1019284, -18.7434211, -10.2397004, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -3.86, NA, 4.45, NA, -4.6, NA, -5.02, NA, -5.87, 
NA, -2.18, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -7.7562386, NA, -7.3204276, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -4.35, 
NA, NA, -4.31, NA, NA, -12.9, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_bankloan = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4547386, 0.12711, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04, 0.39, 
NA, 2.0516206, NA, 3.1071864, 0.363, 0.304, 0.267, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.1743523, NA, 0.0310112, NA, 0.0050652, NA, 
0.0043028, NA, 0.0054514, NA, 0.0084862, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.196, NA, 0.192989, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0436782, NA, NA, 0.0440835, NA, NA, 
0.0147287, NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_bankloan = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.99, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.9, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, 0.99, 
0.99, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, 
NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.95, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.99, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA), iv_mainbl = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.214, NA, -0.007, NA, 
-0.144, NA, -0.107, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_mainbl = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -4.35, NA, -0.18, NA, 
-2.35, NA, -1.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_mainbl = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0491954, NA, 0.0388889, 
NA, 0.0612766, NA, 0.0594444, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_mainbl = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0, NA, 0.95, 
NA, 0.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), iv_number = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.007, NA, 0.004, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-5e-04, NA, NA, -5e-04, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.137, NA, 14.627, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.055, -0.023, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.1054), tstat_iv_number = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4.4171734, NA, 4.4171734, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.7006965, NA, NA, -0.7977768, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.2, 
NA, 3.73, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -4.4171734, -4.4171734, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -8.054), sd_iv_number = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0015847, 
NA, 0.0009056, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000294, 
NA, NA, 0.0006267, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.8553125, NA, 3.9214477, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0124514, 0.005207, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0130867), sig_iv_number = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.9, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.99), iv_lnumber = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.047, NA, -0.443, NA, 0.727, NA, 
1.112, NA, 0.412, NA, 2.296, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.576, NA, 0.3020241, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_lnumber = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3.6103448, NA, -0.4159624, NA, 
1.0370899, NA, 0.4525845, NA, 0.3772894, NA, 0.6288688, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.7343035, 
NA, 7.0203388, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_lnumber = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.29, NA, 1.065, NA, 0.701, NA, 2.457, NA, 1.092, NA, 
3.651, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 2.405, NA, 0.0430213, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_lnumber = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.95, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.99, NA, 0.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), iv_lduration = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.048, NA, -0.647, NA, 0.637, NA, -0.608, NA, 
0.712, NA, -2.711, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), tstat_iv_lduration = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1352113, NA, -0.4961656, NA, 0.9312866, 
NA, -0.2533333, NA, 0.8944724, NA, -1.0187899, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sd_iv_lduration = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.355, NA, 1.304, NA, 0.684, 
NA, 2.4, NA, 0.796, NA, 2.661, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sig_iv_lduration = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 
NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), freedom = c(1654L, 529L, 529L, 529L, 
619L, 619L, 5094L, 5094L, 7751L, 7751L, 7751L, 7751L, 1682L, 
1682L, 1682L, 1682L, 482L, 482L, 482L, 482L, 2263L, 1276L, 
1647L, 630L, 366L, 578L, 283L, 526L, 526L, 348L, 348L, 6725L, 
5503L, 6196L, 2366L, 2366L, 2816L, 2816L, 10570L, 10570L, 
1320L, 1325L, 82L, 124L, 549L, 549L, 788L, 788L, 788L, 788L, 
788L, 788L, 10319L, 1206L, 1206L, 1209L, 1209L, 7811L, 7811L, 
6478L, 6478L, 4316L, 4316L, 4318L, 4318L, 518715L, 518715L, 
519066L, 519066L, 270L, 270L, 271L, 271L, 270L, 270L, 271L, 
271L, 70L, 4291L, 4291L, 4262L, 4262L, 1845L, 1845L, 8446L, 
8446L, 8446L, 8448L, 8448L, 8448L, 8448L, 8448L, 8448L, 6117L, 
2662L, 1932L)), .Names = c("study", "dv_ros", "dv_roa.", 
"dv_roarat", "dv_droa", "dv_roe.", "dv_roerat", "dv_tq", "dv_Inv", 
"dv_ag.", "dv_nop", "dv_rota.", "dv_odpa", "dv_grows", "iv_dummyshare", 
"tstat_iv_dummyshare", "sd_iv_dummyshare", "sig_iv_dummyshare", 
"iv_share", "tstat_iv_share", "sd_iv_share", "sig_iv_share", 
"iv_mainshare", "tstat_iv_mainshare", "sd_iv_mainshare", "sig_iv_mainshare", 
"iv_topshare", "tstat_iv_topshare", "sd_iv_topshare", "sig_iv_topshare", 
"iv_multirel", "tstat_iv_multirel", "sd_iv_multirel", "sig_iv_multirel", 
"iv_bankloan", "tstat_iv_bankloan", "sd_iv_bankloan", "sig_iv_bankloan", 
"iv_mainbl", "tstat_iv_mainbl", "sd_iv_mainbl", "sig_iv_mainbl", 
"iv_number", "tstat_iv_number", "sd_iv_number", "sig_iv_number", 
"iv_lnumber", "tstat_iv_lnumber", "sd_iv_lnumber", "sig_iv_lnumber", 
"iv_lduration", "tstat_iv_lduration", "sd_iv_lduration", "sig_iv_lduration", 
"freedom"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -96L))
```

How can I compute a partial correlation effect between my variables in order to obtain my effect size?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at `pcor()` from the package `ppcor()`. You could also update your post with a small snippet of your data to see what's up

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. Here two screens of the dataset I'm working with:                                                                                                           http://i.stack.imgur.com/4xnCT.png                                         http://i.stack.imgur.com/rxcSp.png                                                                   The screens are taken from Excel but should give an idea of what I'm dealing with

Comment: Anytime. It would be **much** better if you add the structure of your dataset with `dput()`, perhaps `head(dput())` if it's unreasonably large (to your post, not as a comment, for added visibility)

Comment: @erasmortg I got rid of part of it (mainly author, year and some other dummies that I don't need right now) so I posted the dput() output. I tried to look at pcor() but I quite don't get how to make it work with such a dataset as mine

Comment: please check your dput, I am getting errors and am unable to save as an object. You should make it so people can copy and paste your code and get the objects like you have them in your machine

Comment: I changed it and uploaded, I hope it will be fine now but I had to get rid of several variable. Here [link](http://www.filedropper.com/codebook) you can find the full dataset.

Comment: Did you try `pcor(Codebook[2:14])`? Assuming those are the variables and the data.frame is named `Codebook`?

Comment: or which ones are the variables you are interested in?

Comment: If you saw the link I posted the variable I'm interested in are the one that starts with IV, which are the independent variable for which I need to compute the partial correlation effect, the sample variance of the part correlation and the confidence interval

Answer (score 1):

Comments are starting to look a little long, so I'll add my current suggestion as an answer. We could go from there:

```
library(ppcor)
library(dplyr)
#select only columns that start with iv', get the partial correlation
#note that the dataset is named 'df.test' and should be changed
pcor(df.test %>% select(starts_with("iv")))
```

Another possibility is to omit NA from the output, like so:

```
pcor(na.omit(df.test %>% select(starts_with("iv"))))
```

Comment: It does not work. I also get the following warning messages:   Warning messages:
      1: In cov2cor(icvx) :
          diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
      2: In sqrt((n - 2 - gp)/(1 - pcor^2)) : NaN has been computed.                It puzzles me the fact that I don't have to specify the position of the t-stat or the degrees of freedom 'cause the partial correlation can be calculated as Tf/squareroot(Tf^2-dF)

Comment: Warnings do not mean errors, just that the function is going to perform some things automatically. Since the function takes a data.frame as an input, perhaps your original data.frame should be pruned to the most minimal size, and applied via rows not columns (or transposing perhaps).

Comment: I tried to transpose it but it does not work, I get error in solve.default(cvx) : 'a' is 0-diml  What variable do you think I should get rid of? or better, which one should I keep? T-stat, estimators, SE and degrees of freedom?

Comment: I'd keep the estimators. Do you have some guiding literature for this particular analysis?

Comment: Aloe (2014), "an empirical investigation of partial effect size in meta-analysis" regarding partial effect size. On a general level, meta-analysis in economics has still no "classic" textbook. A similar MRA might be the one by Kysucky & Norden (2014), The Benefits of Relationship Lending in a Cross-Country Context: A Meta-Analysis

Comment: let me take a look at both, see what methodologies they use

Comment: I could not find Aloe's reference (at least for free..). Reading  Kysucky & Norden however (sections 4 and 5) suggests taking the estimators (as they choose only papers with multiregressors). To test their second hypothesis, they seem to do a meta regression (and take the rho from there), with weighted least squares estimators and robust variance. `lm` could do that for you (read `help(lm)` or here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lm.html). Here an example that sounds close to what you would need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408439/weighted-least-squares-r

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. Problem is that before doing the meta reg you should compute an effect size, and that is the problem I'm facing right now since I need a partial correlation which I cannot obtain with R

Comment: My other suggestion would be to try to calculate it with your formula 'manually; (instead than taking from a package). Seeing how all of your variables are in a data.set, slicing by rows and applying the formula could be the answer for you.

Comment: I did it manually, [partial correlation csv](http://www.filedropper.com/partcor) regarding the meta reg I was thinking that a multilevel model (Gelman-Hill - 2007) might have been more appropriated, like Klomp-De Haan (2010) "inflation and central bank independence)

Comment: I am hesitant to give advice on subjects I am not very knowledgeable about. Reading your previous literature, weighted least squares seemed like a good option to me, but then again, I do not know anything about the particular characteristics of your dataset

Comment: One last question; I tried to wrote a function for the partial correlation effect, that is _`par_cor <- function(y1, y2) {
  ts <- y1; t2 <- y1*2; df <- (y2);
  pc <- (ts)/(sqrt(t2 + df))
  pc}` if I try to apply it by doing, for example, `par__corr <- par_cor(data$tstat_iv_dummyshare, data$freedom); par_corr`   it works fine. I was wondering if it possible to use an argument to select at once all the columns that starts with "tstat" in order to have all the result in only one vector and print it on my dataset

Comment: Your function takes two arguments, so you either need to subset your data.frame to only the columns that have your required variables and do it manually, or write a wrapper that takes into account all of the pairwise combinations to run the function. A good example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745379/how-can-i-perform-a-pairwise-t-test-in-r-across-multiple-independent-vectors You can switch the t.test for your ad-hoc function and get the results as an object

Answer (score 1):

Following the formulas provided by Aloe & Thompson, "the synthesis of partial effect size" I used the following functions to compute them:

```
par_cor <- function(y1, y2) {
ts <- y1; ts2 <- y1*2; df <- (y2);
pc <- (ts)/(sqrt(ts2 + df))
pc}
```

I then bind together the output of the different functions using:

```
pc <- pmin(par_corr, par_corr1, par_corr2, par_corr3, ... , na.rm = TRUE)
```

Where ts is the t-stat of the interessed independent variable and df is the regression degrees of freedom. I then computed the variance by doing:

```
par_corVAR <- function(y1, y2) {
pc <- y1; df <- y2;
pcv <- ((1-pc^2)^2)/(df)
pcv}
```

It's not very elegant but it does the trick. Thanks for your help!